# first memcpy into buffer faster than direct access to pixels of CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, core-video, core-media

I noticed that accessing the pixels returned by `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` directly (I'm using two nested for-loops) is about 100 times slower than first allocating a buffer with malloc, memcpy the pixels into that buffer and then accessing the pixels in that buffer. Why is that?

Comment: I have not noticed this. I use this to flip images in real time coming from the camera. Are you locking the address? CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress.

Comment: Yes, I use CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress.

Comment: Could this be that the memory that is returned from `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` is on the camera chip rather than the main system memory and the camera chip's memory access is slower?